# Linux - Is there a way to fake the highest directory?

Tags: linux, rpm

`/` is the highest directory in Linux.  Is there a way to fake that to something else say `/opt/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT`?

Here's my problem space.  I am trying to re-package a COTS into RPM format.  The COTS came in a form of binary and I need to install that first before packaging it into RPM.  The install is installing it into `/opt/app` directory, and I want it to install it into `/opt/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opt/app` but I couldn't force that to happen.

Comment: Setup a chroot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chroot /opt/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT` can do this, but it requires that you have a working OS installed within the chroot directory.

Instead of using chroot, a simpler option would be to create a symlink from /opt/app to /opt/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opt/app:

```
mkdir -p /opt/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opt/app
ln -s /opt/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opt/app /opt/app
```

Then the installation will think it's working in /opt/app, but will in fact go into /opt/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/opt/app.

Comment: Symlinks will not work if they refer a file/folder outside the root jail. Actually they will be relative to jail's root folder. You can use hardlinks or, better, bind mounts.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  The key is chroot but like you said you need to have a working OS installed within the chroot directory.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici:  I think I wasn't clear.  I meant instead of chroot, not with it.  Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into `man chroot`, this should help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I totally forgot about the chroot command.

Answer (score 0):

What you want, but you may not have asked in your question is this: a *combination* of **chroot** and **overlayfs**

```
modprobe overlay
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/,upperdir=/home/overlay/root_fs/upper,workdir=/home/overlay/root_fs/work /home/overlay/root_fs/root_slash
cd /home/overaly/root_fs/root_slash
chroot .
```

*I mean*: you'll need 'overlay file system' kernel module and necessary userspace tools to mount it; you'll also need these three folders - one for work, one for upper where the changes will be saved and the chroot one. This way you can use as a base your O.S. with all media's mounted, shares, etc and on top write only changes to the overlay file system.
The changes in your case are the 'installation files'.